# TYPO3 - realurl uppercase path not working in 2.3.0 anymore

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.x

Uppercase realurl path not working after upgrading realurl from 2.2.1 to 2.3.0. Prior to the upgrade I ran this script as suggested:

https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Installing-and-enabling-the-extension#update-to-realurl-230-from-lower-2x-versions

... but now I can't access a record when using the uppercase path like:

domain/id/123D45WTA7/

I then get a page not found. The record and the link is working when using:

domain/id/123d45wta7/

... the original ID of the record is uppercase though: 123D45WTA7 ... and I need to access the record when entering uppercase path into the browser.

Any idea how I can access the record with uppercase again?

Comment: Version 2.3.0 has just been relaunched. If it's a bug you should contribute this as an issue on Github

Comment: Hi Paul ... I did: https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/issues/543 . By relaunch you mean the 2.3.0 has been launched again? Should I deactivate my 'old' 2.3.0 and install the 'updated' 2.3.0 ?

Comment: No sorry it was just a typo(3) :-p I mean it has just been released - there was no relaunch!

Comment: Ok  :-) ... then I think I will downgrade in meantime ...